# Abstract Classes and virtual methods problems: "cannot allocate an object of abstract type"

Tags: c++, abstract-class, abstract

I have this classes:

```
class IDescriptor
{
public:

    virtual float compare(IDescriptor *D) = 0;
};

class DescHistogram : public IDescriptor
{
public:

    vector<float> desc;
    DescHistogram(vector<float> vd);
    ~DescHistogram();
    float compare(DescHistogram *D);
    // ALL THESE FUNCTIONS ARE IMPLEMENTED IN THE SOURCE CPP FILE.
};
```

and in some place in my code I do this initalization:

```
vector<float> hist;
[...] // filling the vector.
DescHistogram *myDesc = new DescHistogram(hist);
point.setDescriptor(myDesc);
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘DescHistogram’
note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘DescHistogram’:
note:   virtual float IDescriptor::compare(IDescriptor*)
```

I have some questions about this:

What is the reason of this error? 
What type must be the parameter of `DescHistogram::compare`? I understand that it can be a derived type, isn't it?
A constructor is needed by the abstract class `IDescriptor`?

Maybe it's an stupid error, but I didn't find any solution for my case. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the reason of this error?

`DescHistogram` doesn't override `IDescriptor::compare` with a compatible function, so it's still abstract and can't be instantiated.

> What type must be the parameter of `DescHistogram::compare`?

`IDescriptor`, to match the function it overrides. It must be callable with any type that the base-class function accepts, and so can't be a more derived type.

> I understand that it can be a derived type, isn't it?

No. It has to be the same type.

> A constructor is needed by the abstract class `IDescriptor`?

No. It already has an implicit default constructor, and doesn't need anything else to be instantiated as part of a non-abstract derived class.

Comment: Ok, I understand now that the compare function in DescHistogram must have a IDescriptor as a parameter. However, now, in my DescHistogram implementation I have to work with the vector<float> desc. In this case, the compliler don't accept this, because desc is not a part of IDescriptor. What I have to do?

Comment: @froure: Dynamic cast the `IDescriptor*` into `DescHistogram*` inside your compare method.

Comment: Ok, it works! Thank you very much!!! I've learned something more about abstraction! Thaaaanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

You **did not implement the `virtual compare()` function in `DescHistogram`**. You implemented another `compare()` function:

```
virtual float compare(IDescriptor *D) = 0; // in class IDescriptor
        float compare(DescHistogram *D);   // in class DescHistogram
```

This other `compare()` function does not implement the `virtual` function of the base hence `DescHistogram` is still abstract.

If it makes no sense to compare between different types (such as `DescHistogram`) derived from `IDescriptor`, then your code design is flawed. You can still get your code working using RTTI, i.e. via

```
class DescHistogram : public IDescriptor
{
  float compare_self(DescHistogram *D); // tolerates nullptr input
public:
  float compare(IDescriptor *D)
  {
    return compare_self(dynamic_cast<DescHistogram*>(D));
  }
};
```

but this can be inefficient. Moreover, `compare_self` serves no sensible independent purpose (as a consequence of the design flaw).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the compare function in DescHistogram

Comment: The compare function is already defined and implemented (in the cpp file). I don't understand what you saying. Sorry :P

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written here you to define an implementation of `compare` for `DescHistogram` (and NOT also mark it as pure `virtual`).

Comment: THe comprare function is implemented in my cpp file. Maybe I should specify it in my question.

Comment: @froure if you have an implementation in a .cpp file somewhere I'd suggest adding that to the question.  Something is causing your compiler to not find that implementation